# How to call Php soap based service from .Net Application

Tags: c#, .net, soap, desktop-application

My php application soap based service is accepting array as a paramter. when i call that service  from PHP client it works fine. here is my php cLIENT Code.

```
function pending_sms_request() {
    $option = array(
        'location' => 'http://demo.management.com/sms_manage/soap_web_service',
        'uri' => 'http://demo.management.com/'
    );
    $client = new SoapClient(NULL, $option);
    $param = array('Key' => '12', 'ID' => 4);
    $result = $client->__soapCall('pending_sms', array('parameter' => $param));
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(json_decode($result));
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

but i am unable to call my service from .Net client.please any body can help.how can i convert this php client code into .Net .so that i can call Php soap based service.really thankfull if some body give me solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a reference to your Service(or WSDL file) 
create client instance and call the functions with desired parameters it is as simple as that

Comment: i have not a WSDL url.when i add reference it doesn't find the service via this url. but when i call service through my php client it call the method properly and give me respone.how can i call that service without reference.

Comment: Then add a reference to your service using the link to your web service it should work just fine since it contains the metadata of your service